# How to optimize parameters with orthogonal constraints?

Tags: optimization, linear-transformations, nonlinear-optimization

I'm working on a Compute Vision problem. It can be defined by the formula below:
$$
minimize \ f(T) \\
s.t \ T = \begin{bmatrix}
    R & t \\
    0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}， R^TR = I， {det}(R) = 1
$$
Where $I$ is $3\times3$ identity matrix, $f$ is non-linear objective function without gradient.
I'd like to using non-linear optimization like Powell's method to optimize the objective function, however, I don't know how to define the parameters.

$T$ is a $4\times4$ matrix with 12 unknown parameters($R_{3\times3}$,$t_{3\times1}$), however, I can't optimize these 12 parameters directly since there is a orthogonal constraints with $R$.

Since $R$ has only 3 dof, I assumed that I only need to optimize 3 parameter to get the best $R$, is it right? If so, how can I compute the $R$ with 3 parameters?

Answer (score 1):

One way to circumvent the constraints imposed by $R$ is to consider a surjective map from $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, the space of $3$-by-$3$ skew-symmetric matrices, to $SO(3)$, the special orthogonal group, i.e. $3$-by-$3$ orthogonal matrices with determinant 1. Examples include the exponential map $\exp:\mathfrak{so}(3)\to SO(3)$ and the [Cayley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform). The latter maps skew symmetric matrices to special orthogonal matrices via $S\mapsto (I-S)(I+S)^{-1}$ where $I$ is the $3$-by-$3$ identity (this isn't actually surjective, but it is a surjection onto the full-measure open subset of special orthogonal matrices that do not have $-1$ as an eigenvalue). Note
\begin{align*}
\mathfrak{so}(3) = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & s_1 & s_2 \\ -s_1 & 0 & s_3 \\ -s_2 & -s_3 & 0 \end{pmatrix}:(s_1,s_2,s_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3\right\}.
\end{align*}
Letting $g:\mathfrak{so}(3)\to SO(3)$ be your chosen map, the optimization problem becomes
\begin{align*}
\text{minimize}\ f(T)\quad \text{with}\quad T=\begin{pmatrix} g(s) & t \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
where now $s,t\in\mathbb{R}^3$ are unconstrained parameters.